# Use Android baseadapter as adapter for pager view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-viewpager

I've seen a bunch of examples and tutorials on how to create a pager adapter but what if you need to feed the data from a remote database? If I am already using a base adapter to populate my listview, can I use the same adapter for a pager view? Without using fragments either

Comment: no you can't. If you want to use viewpager with adapter you must use PagerAdapter. And create your listviews with your baseadapter in PagerAdapter instantiateItem() method.

Comment: @Selim YILDIZ ok, so if I understand you correctly, I would instantiate the views the same as I would in an activity's onCreate() method?

Comment: you must create a class exented by pageradapter and override methods. after you set ViewPager setadapter that. You can create listview on your custom PagerAdapter  instantiateItem()  method like that  ListView list = new ListView(context)